# Error when calling std::find on a user-defined object

Tags: c++, iterator, find, hashtable, operator-keyword

So I keep get error message called:

> no match for 'operator==' in '(&__first) >std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator* with _Tp = Course == __val'

in the following code:

```
int main(){
  Course NOT_FOUND("NOT_FOUND", "NOT_FOUND", 0);
  Course x("COMP2611", "COMPUTER ORGANIAZTION", 2);
  HashTable<Course> q(NOT_FOUND, 17, 36);

  q.insert(x);
}



template <class HashedObj>
class HashTable{
public:
  HashTable(const HashedObj& notFound, int bucket, int base);
  void insert(const HashedObj& x);

private:
  const HashedObj ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
  vector<list<HashedObj> > theList;
};

template <class HashedObj>
void HashTable<HashedObj>::insert(const HashedObj& x){
  list<HashedObj>& whichList = theList[hash(x)];
  typename list<HashedObj>::iterator itr;
  itr = std::find(theList[0].begin(), theList[0].end(), x);
  if(itr == theList[hash(x)].end())
    whichList.insert(theList[hash(x)].begin(), x);
}
```

I tested and understand the error is from the line

```
itr = std::find(theList[0].begin(), theList[0].end(), x);
```

But I don't know what to do to fix it. I think I am just calling
standard find function here, but apparently it does not work.

The class Course is defined correctly I think, because I tested in other classes before.

The code is:

```
class Course{
public:
Course(string code, string name, int credit):
    _code(code), _name(name), _credit(credit){}

string _code;

private:
string _name;
int _credit;

friend int hash(Course x);
};


int hash(Course x){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x._name.size(); i++)
        sum+=_name[i];

    return sum % 35;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`find` uses `operator==` to compare the parameter you are looking for to the value of the iterator. Your `Course` class has no such `operator==`. You need to implement it.

```
class Course {
public:
  // bla bla
  friend
  bool operator==(const Course& x, const Course& y)
  { return your-comparison-code-here; }
};
```

As James Kanze points out: You can also use `std::find_if` and provide a comparison functor/lambda.

Comment: Alternatively, he can use `find_if`, and provide a comparator.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, it's so helpful!

Comment: @user1819047 If this answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking the check-mark. Also have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get to know stackoverflow.